# Obtendo o caminho completo de um arquivo do cliente em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, arquivo, webforms

Do lado do servidor, é possível obter caminho completo de um arquivo enviado por um cliente utilizando a tag `<input type="file">`?

Por exemplo, se o usuário enviar o arquivo `C:\Users\Documents\a.txt`, tem como o servidor conseguir a string `C:\Users\Documents\a.txt`?

Comment: Já tentou `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);`? Pode colocar o que você tentou ou um trecho que está tentando fazer?

Comment: filename no caso é o name="" que coloca na tag input certo ?

Comment: por enquanto só fiz o <input type="file" name"foto">

Comment: Pode ser, mas é uma propriedade que vai ter o nome do arquivo que foi carregado no servidor. Você já viu este exemplo? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Webforms, preciso somente pegar o path do aquivo que foi selecionado

Comment: O IE pega o caminho completo do cliente

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A partir do servidor não é possível pegar o path de um arquivo submetido pelo cliente, por restrições de segurança.

O máximo que você obterá é o nome do arquivo, seu tamanho, extensão e MIME.

Por exemplo, se o cliente submeter o arquivo `C:\A\B\C\Teste.txt`, o máximo que você conseguirá no servidor é o nome `Teste.txt`.

Comment: Eu acho (ou achava) que ele quer o *path* no servidor, se for no lado cliente, como você sugere, aí não tem jeito mesmo. É que pensei só no jeito que dá :)

Comment: Pois é, a pergunta ficou meio vaga... Mas acho mesmo que é isso :)

Comment: sim, isso mesmo rafa, como posso fazer tipo o PHP que tem o move_uploaded_files ?

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi então, com o `move_uploaded_files` você pega o arquivo que foi enviado para o servidor e manda para um *path* que você deseja. É o oposto desta resposta.

Comment: não, move_upload_files só copia o arquivo do path origem pra algum path de desejo(que pode ser um servidor ou não), é somente isso que desejo fazer

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi Você não entendeu o que o bigown disse, vocês estão dizendo a mesma coisa...

Comment: então, no caso só desejo fazer a mesma coisa.

Comment: Então @EnzoTiezzi, se o que você quer é parecido com o `move_uploaded_files` do PHP, como esta resposta responde o que você precisa?

Comment: como seria apenas local, eu fazer meio que uma gambiarra, pegar o path do arquivo, usar um process pra rodar um comando COPY pra uma pasta desejada

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi é, não dá para entender o que você deseja. Você fala em servidor, depois fala em local. Você fala que quer algo igual ao `move_uploaded_files` só que usando ASP.Net, depois fala que vai fazer copy do OS.

Comment: Seguinte, quero pegar um arquivo e fazer a copia do mesmo para outra pasta, como isso é feito??? você pega o path do arquivo origem e faz um COPY para a pasta desejada, isso o move_uploaded_file faz, e é isso que desejo fazer no asp.net, o move_uploaded_file funciona tanto local como em servidor, por isso que tanto faz a maneira, porque no final dos casos será um usuário que fará o upload do arquivo

Answer (score 8):

Depois de várias alterações na proposta inicial da pergunta eu tenho que dizer que não é possível pegar o *path* de um arquivo local em um navegador em um serviço que esteja em um servidor a não ser por uma falha de segurança eventual em alguma versão específica, mas isto, em hipótese alguma, deve considerado. Mesmo que este serviço esteja na mesma máquina que o navegador, não é possível sem uma intervenção tão maluca que existem outros meios mais fáceis e corretos para resolver o problema, que é o que importa.

Se há esta garantia que o servidor e o navegador estão na mesma máquina, para que usar um navegador para resolver este problema? Não faz sentido. Deve-se usar a melhor ferramenta para o problema. Não tentar adaptar o problema para a ferramenta. Não podemos nos fixar em um caminho para resolver o problema, devemos achar uma solução para o problema.

Com os indicações que disponho, principalmente em comentários, de como você está fazendo, o melhor que eu posso postar é isso:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnUpload_Click" text="Upload" onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
</form>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/CaminhoArquivoCliente.cs).

Code Behind

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Uploads/" + fileName));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/CaminhoArquivoCliente.cs).

Isso faz exatamente o que você precisa, até onde deu para entender. Claro que você vai ter que adaptar às características específicas do sue código. Mas o centro da questão está aí.

Veja a [documentação do método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Web_UI_WebControls_FileUpload_SaveAs_System_String_) que faz o mesmo que o `move_uploaded_files`.

Comment: Se for o caso de ler o arquivo basta usar o `FileUpload.FileContent` assim  `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileUpload.FileContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))`